# system grep inside a perl script gives unbalanced parenthesis

Tags: perl, grep, system

```
system ("grep -E 'Type|group|slack ('  $a > temp.rpt");
```

The above line is giving me an error `Unmatched ( or \(`

What is wrong here?

I have tried a backslash before `(` too. it shows the same error.

Comment: What is `$a`? Is this a filename, built earlier in the script?

Answer (score 6):

Since you are in a script, why not do that in Perl?

```
my $infile = '...';
open my $fh,     '<', $infile   or die "Can't open $file: $!";
open my $out_fh, '>', $temp.rpt or die "Can't open $temp.rpt: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    print $out_fh $_  if /Type|group|slack \(/; 
}
```

Adjust your regex as needed.  Generally, it is far easier to change and tweak things now.

If the input file isn't too large you can process in one line as well, once you opened files

```
print $out_fh grep { /Type|group|slack \(/ } <$fh>;
```

The [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) imposes the *list context* on the [<> operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators) so it reads and at once returns all lines in a list, and the ones that pass the condition are printed.

---

A comment on regex. As it stands, it matches either `Type` or `group` or `slack (`.  If, by any chance, you intend to match either of the words, then followed by space-paren, you need grouping parenthesis, `/(?:Type|group|slack) \(/`.  The `?:` is there so it is not needlessly captured.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use three backslashes

```
system ("grep -E 'Type|group|slack \\\('  $a ");
```

Comment: Why three specifically?

Answer (score 0):

`(` is a regex metacharacter in `grep -E`. That's why you get the error.

Adding a single backslash doesn't fix it because that's processed by perl: `"\("` is the same string as `"("`.

To fix it, you need to either use two backslashes (`"\\("`, which turns into the two character string `\(`, which is then interpreted by `grep`), or remove the `-E` option because `(` isn't special in POSIX "basic" regexes (which is what `grep` uses by default).